# split mixed description hashtags and text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
var string = "#developers must split #hashtags";
```

I want to split it when a word starts with # symbol

I tried these two examples

```
var example1 = string.split(/(?=#)/g);

//result is ["#developers must split ", "#hashtags"]

var example2 = string.split(/(?:^|[ ])#([a-zA-Z]+)/g);

// result is ["", "developers", "must split", "hashtags", ""]
```

Result must looks like this

```
var description = ["#developers", "must split", "#hashtags"]
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/g5esmabd/1/)

I have a solution but it is a bit long, I want it short with regex. thank you,

Comment: You say you only want it to split by each hashtag, but you also reiterate that `must split` should also be split. Why? I'm failing to understand what the issue with your examples are. They both seem to do what you're kind of looking for.

Comment: I don't wanna iterate on each word, just on hashtags and sentences. the second example is near but, not keeping the separator "#" and adding some more items empty.

Comment: You can put the code from that JSFiddle into a runnable snippet right here in your question.  I think it's better to have the runnable example be right here in the question.

Comment: Did you try splitting on `(#\S+)`

Comment: @Wyck it works, but also needs to add a filter for empty items string.split(/(#\S+)/).filter(item => item);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split, the captured groups are included in the split results array.  So you can capture the `#word` delimiter and omit the space before and after the delimiter with an expression like `\s*(#\S+)\s*`.  Omit empty strings by `filter`-ing on an expression that tests the truthiness of each string (e.g.: `x => x`).

```js
let result = "#developers must split #hashtags".split(/\s*(#\S+)\s*/g).filter(x => x);
console.log(result);
```